# Is it possible to define global variables in a function and use the variable in other function using preprocessor directives in C++?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to understand the preprocessor directives (like #if , #ifdef, #ifndef) and following is the code I have tried out.

[image: Main_class.cpp]
[image: Wrap.h file]
[image: Output]

Note: The member functions are further wrapped and used in python and hence the results show the python like calls but this does not affect any of the c++ process.

Question: 1. As per my understanding the global variables have a scope of whole file from the point it is declared. Then in this case, why is the defined value not accepted inside another function?

Requirement: I want to do something like mentioned below:

```
void Somefunc(int val){
 set variable x;
}
```

Based on the x value, I want to include functions. Now the condition is:
If x=1, only some functions should be compiled since others utilize headers which would throw errors with the compiler I am using.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessing runs before compilation. It handles the source code as plain text, it doesn't care for C++ language semantics.

The reason why `var` is not defined is that a preprocessor definition is valid from the point of definition until the end of the file (preprocessed translation unit) or a corresponding `#undef`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out @krisz ! If that is the case I am adding my requirement in details which i thought could be done using global variables.